# C program terminating

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to write a program in C (in Linux 64bit with GCC 4.1.2).

```
int program_instances(char *cmdname)
{
   char buf[32], *ret;
   char cmdbuf[512];
   FILE *cmdpipe;

   sprintf(cmdbuf, "/bin/ps -eo comm | /bin/grep -c '%s'",
      cmdname);
   cmdpipe = popen(cmdbuf, "r");

   if (!cmdpipe)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
   ret = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), cmdpipe);
   pclose(cmdpipe);

   if (!ret)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   int nr = atoi(buf);
   return nr;
}
```

Tried to debug the issue through gdb but after the line

```
sprintf(cmdbuf, "/bin/ps -eo comm | /bin/grep -c '%'",cmdname);
```

The programm is not crossing the above line , throwing the below lines..

```
Executing new program: /bin/bash
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
[New process 2437]
Executing new program: /bin/ps
```

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: How long is cmdname? You might be sprinting off the end of cmdbuf.

Comment: "*Please help us to resolve this issue*" - Which issue? The hang or the message from gdb?

Comment: This is C, not really C++, you might get answer quicker if you add that tag

Comment: Rob: the programm is crashing.. i.e Hang

Comment: @user1774057: Crashes and hangs are two different kinds of failure.  Using the wrong terminology makes it very difficult for people to help you.

Comment: @ben : changed accordingly.. thanks

Comment: Those `gdb` messages look a bit as if you have set the GDB option to follow child processes: `set follow-fork-mode child` or thereabouts.

Comment: @jonathan : yes, you are correct.. If I didn't give such option the program is crashing @ fork. so I gave that option

Comment: Have you tried running your program with valgrind?

Comment: Also, since this is string manipulation being passed to `popen`, I think that [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) is apropos.

Answer (score 3):

Try to compile your code with -g and remove -O [compiler flag]. When optimizing compiler(gcc) changes order of instructions to improve speed. After recompiling attach debugger again.

Comment: Again, I am going to say what I normally do in such situation. Please use logs like this, and try to run it outside of debugger: printf("%s : %d\n", _ _ FILE _ _ , _ _ LINE _ _); place this line before and after where you think problem happens